# How to select elements in a tensor conditional upon their indices

Tags: tensors

I have a tensor, u, of rank one, meaning that I have a matrix whose elements are themselves matrices. I would like to select, and make a list of, only those sub-matrices whose indices comply with the condition `j < k`, i.e. the row index is always smaller than the column index.

This effectively corresponds to strictly *upper-triangularising* the tensor. Once I select the correct sub-matrices, I would like them to appear in a list sorted row by row. I.e., if each sub-matrix is called `aXX`, where `XX` are the row and column indices, and the tensor has dimensions `NxN`, then I want the list to look like this:

```
a12, a13, a14 ..., a1N, a23, a24, ..., a2N, a34, ..., a3N, ..., a(N-1)N.
```

I have tried using `UpperTriangularize[]` to no avail. I suspect the answer must be using `Select[]` or `Pick[]`, but I am unsure of how to implement the condition based on testing the indices of the tensor. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here is my code which generates u. `NLevel` is the same as `N` that I mentioned above, and can be varied with each run of the programme.

```
 P = Table[SparseArray[{{j, k} -> 1}, {NLevel, NLevel}], {j, NLevel}, {k, NLevel}]
 u = Table[P[[1, j, k]] + P[[1, k, j]], {j, NLevel}, {k, NLevel}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following solution is easier to follow:

```
Join @@ Table[ u[[j,k]] , {j, NLevel}, {k, j + 1, NLevel}]
```

The `Table` part should be self-explanatory: it iterates through $a_{jk}$ for pairs $j < k$.  However, it does not return a list of matrices.  It returns a list of lists of matrices.  These need to be joined together into a single list, which is what `Join @@` does.

References:

- [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html)
- [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)

Comment: I agree. It's much easier to see what is going on here. In my case, I find neverthess that I need to add a '1,' before 'j,k' in `u[[j,k]]`, i.e.: `Join @@ Table[ u[[1, j, k]], {j, NLevel}, {k, j + 1, NLevel}] // MatrixForm`, otherwise I get an error. I think this has to do with the extra pair of brackets that Mathematica likes to put around P and u.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Part`:

```
NLevel = 3;
P = Table[SparseArray[{{j, k} -> 1}, {NLevel, NLevel}], {j, NLevel}, {k, NLevel}];

P[[##]] & @@@ Subsets[Range@Length@P, {2}] // Normal

(* {{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
   {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}} *)
```

Instead of `Subsets[Range@Length@P, {2}]` we can also use `SparseArray[UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {NLevel, NLevel}],  1]]["NonzeroPositions"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you want (using your `u` example *without* the `MatrixForm` formatting):

```
Normal@Extract[#, Sort@Join[Array[{#, #} &, Length@#], Subsets[Range@Length@#, {2}]]] &[u]

(*
{{{2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}}
*)
```

Edit: Sorry, I think I misread your question. If it's strictly upper,

```
Normal@Extract[#, Subsets[Range@Length@#, {2}]] &[u]
```